# Typed list typespec never breaks the contract

Tags: elixir, dialyzer, typespec

If you define a typespec and use a different type of parameter it will display an error similar to:

```
binary() ... breaks the contract ... boolean()
```

For example this typespec:

```
@spec check?(binary) :: boolean
```

But it doesnt seem to work for a typed List, or at least, it will never display the warning, if I have a method which receives a list of strings I would define this typespec:

```
@spec check?([String.t]) :: boolean
```

I can then define any spec for the list and it will never complain when running a dialyzer, i.e:

```
@spec check?(list(boolean)) :: boolean
@spec check?(list(Conn)) :: boolean
@spec check?(list(number)) :: boolean
@spec check?(list(integer)) :: boolean
```

Is that intended? it looks like if I defined a list with any type `[any()]`

Is there other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that all the list types include the empty list as a valid value.

For example, in the following case:

- you call the function with a possibly empty list of booleans
- the function accepts a possibly empty list of strings

Dialyzer will conclude that there is a possible solution, namely if the list is empty.  Since Dialyzer only prints warnings if it can conclude that a certain piece of code will always crash, it doesn't print one in this case.

I'm not aware of any good solution to this.  If you want to explicitly require non-empty lists, you can use e.g. `nonempty_list(boolean)` instead of `list(boolean)`.